# Google Drive SDK auth - Recovering from incorrect account selection

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am using using gapi.auth.authorize to authenticate someone before viewing a document. If they login with the wrong account, I will get a file not found error from the  Drive API. When I catch this error, I want to log them out and force them to pick a different account. When I try doing this, the popup shows up and immediately closes selecting the previous account they already had.

Is there a standard way to force the user to switch accounts?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you doing today? Can you include some code in your post.